# Did my math textbook make a typo?

Tags: graph-theory, connectedness, path-connected

My textbook defined connectedness in graphs in the following way:

> A graph  *G(V, E)*  is said to be **connected** if for every pair of vertices *u* and *v* there is a path in *G* from *u* to *v*.

The textbook then asks the reader to complete the following exercise:

> Show by giving an example that there are connected graphs in which there is no path that goes through all the vertices.

I take the exercise as impossible to complete.  By definition, connected graphs are those in which there is some path that goes through all the vertices.  Might I have misunderstood either the definition or exercise?  Could it be possible that the textbook made a typo?

Any advice or clarification would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The definition never said there was a path between all of the vertices it just said there was a path between every pair of vertices.

Comment: While there may be a every pair of vertices, there is not necessarily a single path through all the vertices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A connected graph means that between any two vertices, there is some path. For example if the two vertices share an edge, there is a path between them consisting of just that single edge.

This says nothing about whether or not there is a single path that goes through all the vertices in some order. Remember that by definition a path cannot visit any vertex more than once. So as you go from one vertex to the next, it might not be possible to visit all vertices without re-visiting a previous one.

Comment: Thank you Jaap!  Your answer along with Peter's was great help.  You gave me that aha moment with your reminder that a path cannot visit any vertex more than once.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to explain may be to provide a solution to the question. Consider the graph on $4$ vertices given by
$$G=(\{1,2,3,4\},\{(1,2),(1,3),(1,4)\})$$
Then for every pair of vertices there is a path between them (so $G$ is connected) but there is no path connecting every vertex.

Comment: Peter, in your solution, is it possible to go from 4 to 3 by visiting 1 in between?  And if so, is that a path?

Comment: Yes as I said every pair has a path between them. In that case the path would be $\{(1,4),(1,3)\}$.